# caption without figure envirorment

Tags: captions

I'm making a report with a latex editor. I have a caption made up by two pictures in a column. The picture below is larger than that of above, and I use center envirorment without 'figure' in order to obtain the pictures aligned. I only use \includegraphics. Does anybody know how can I put the pictures a 'subcaption' like (a),(b) withou the figure envirorment?? because if I use it the picture below appears not aligned. Thanks

Comment: The `figure` environment has nothing to do with alignment. You can use the `center` environment inside the figure environment, or better still use `\centering`.

Comment: I've tried, but the picture below is not aligned..The fact is that this picture (the large picture below) was made with mathematica coupling two different figures, and I think that it can't be aligned within the figure or center environment for this reason...

Comment: As I said, the `figure` environment has nothing to do with alignment. You will need to provide a complete example code that reproduces the problem in order to get help. You can make images available for download from elsewhere and add links to your question if necessary.

Comment: Your approach is, well, hackish. We understand you have two pictures, one larger than the other. But the layout depends on the page layout. You mention a column, so is it a two column layout of the whole text? You see, we can't just give two or three commands which solve your issue now, because it depends on the setup of your report.

Answer (score 1):

Here two different packages are used `subcaption` and `subfig` for demonstration. Without `figure` environment, one could use `minipage` environment with `columnwidth` setting and seek helps from

```
\makeatletter
\def\@captype{figure}
\makeatother
```

If `List of Figures` is desired then use `\caption{...}`, `\listofigures` commands and compile twice to get the proper rendering.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2cm]{geometry}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{multicol}
   \columnsep=10pt 
   \columnseprule=3pt 
%   \usepackage{subfig}       % for subfloat
   \usepackage{subcaption}    % for subcaptionbox
   \usepackage{graphicx} 
   %\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
   \usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{multicols}{2} 

\lipsum[1-3]
\vfill
\columnbreak

% to run this session, please disable `sufig` package and enable `subcaption` package

\subsection*{Subcaptionbox section}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\makeatletter
\def\@captype{figure}
\makeatother
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Above  \label{fig:above}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}\\
  \subcaptionbox{Below  \label{fig:below}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image-b} }
  \caption{Two figures}\label{Fig}
\end{minipage}

% to run this session, please disable `subcaption` package and enable `subfig` package

%\subsection*{Subfloat section}
%
%\noindent
%\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
%\makeatletter
%\def\@captype{figure}
%\makeatother
% \centering
%  \subfloat[Above]{%
%  \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
%  \label{fig:above}
%}\\
%  \subfloat[Below]{%
%  \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
%  \label{fig:below}
%}
%  \caption{Two figures,\label{Fig}}
%\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is essentially what `\captionof` of the `capt-of` package does. But since you're using `subcaption`, the command `\captionof` is already available: `\captionof{figure}{<text>}`

Comment: Thanks for the insights @egreg. Should find time to study those package codes. Anyway, the proposal is what I know of to tackle such question. Appreciated.