# How to put caption under image without using \begin{figure}?

Tags: tables, graphics, floats, captions

I need to put an image inside table. I can't use figure inside table. Will not work even if I add minipage.

But can add `\includegraphics` OK inside table. But now I am not able to use `\caption` any more. It looks like `\caption{}` only works with `figure`.

The question is, how to add caption, but without using figure? Here is MWE.

First the version that **does not** work

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2in}}
    \begin{figure}    
       \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
       \caption{my caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

so removed figure.  But like to use caption, or caption like thing

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2in}}
    %\begin{figure}    
       \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
       \caption{my caption} %only when commenting this will it compile
    %\end{figure}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to get something similar to what is obtained when using figure
but without using figure, since figure can't be used inside tables.

Is there something that has same semantics as `\caption` but does not need `figure` to use?

What is the best way to do this? Please note I only use lualatex to compile.

TL 2020.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204058/197451

Comment: @jsbibra  it does not work. Not inside table. I just tried it. `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2in}}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\makeatletter
\def\@captype{figure}
\makeatother
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Two figures}\label{Fig}
\end{minipage}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}`

Comment: This is not entirely trivial. You can use the `caption` package and use `\captionof{figure}{...}`. But even this requires some work, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148646/194703.

Answer (score 2):

This redefines `\caption` locally (inside the `\parbox`).  Every cell in a p column is a separate `\parbox`.

`\caption@caption` is the original name used by the caption package.  This uses `\csname` to implement the @ symbol, which in turn requires `\expandafter`s.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2in}}
   \expandafter\let\expandafter\caption\csname caption@caption\endcsname
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
   \captionof{figure}{my caption}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

This creates a new name which doesn't include an @ symbol.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\let\normalcaption=\caption

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2in}}
   \let\caption=\normalcaption
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
   \captionof{figure}{my caption}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```